# Why doesn't a nested await point yield up to tokio::select

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I think I'm missing something very basic.  My expectation is that when `tick.tick()` completes and starts the `sleep` loop, `tokio::time::sleep(...).await` should yield back to the select statement, allowing `longer_tick` a chance to complete.  But once the shorter tick completes, this gets stuck in the sleep loop, never yielding back to select.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ddb47ab0cd5669def5ea0596803381a8

```
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::time::interval;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut tick = interval(Duration::from_millis(500));
    let mut longer_tick = interval(Duration::from_millis(1000));

    loop {
        tokio::select! {
            _ = longer_tick.tick() => {
                println!("longer tick");
            },
            _ = tick.tick() => {
                println!("sleeping");
                sleep().await;
            },
        }
    }
}

async fn sleep() {
    let mut idx = 0;
    loop {
        let time = idx.min(5);
        println!("Sleeping for {} s", time);
        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(time)).await;
        idx += 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tokio's [select](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/macro.select.html) only waits for the futures in the branch section, not the handler. So the `sleep` future is not considered when using `select!`.

Also, per the documentation

> Waits on multiple concurrent branches, returning when the first branch completes, cancelling the remaining branches.

When one of the branch completes (the `interval`'s in this case), the other branches are cancelled.
Therefore when you are using `select`, it will only ever execute one of the branch handlers.

Comment: I understood the cancellation part, which is why `select` was nested inside a `loop`.  I didn't realize the bit about the handler though - thanks.  I suppose that makes sense though - the "handler" here should really be empty, and the sleep should be moved into the branch.

Comment: @Josh if you remove the loop in the sleep, you may see them alternate